# Ubuntu – 120hz / 144hz not appearing on Nvidia X Server with HDMI

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, display-resolution, nvidia-settings

**My current setup is as follows:**

I have a main Windows PC connected to [2x AORUS AD27QD monitors](https://www.gigabyte.com/Monitors/AD27QD#kf) via DisplayPort cables. These both run at 2560 x 1440 at 144hz with no issues at all. I also have a Ubuntu GNU/Linux machine (version 18.04.3 LTS) connected to one of the AORUS AD27QD monitors using HDMI, which runs at 2560 x 1440 at 60Hz. The idea is I switch sources between DisplayPort and HDMI depending on if I want a second monitor for windows or to use Ubuntu on that one screen.

The problem is on Ubuntu whenever I go into the Nvidia X Server program and try to select a refresh rate higher than 60Hz there is no other option than 60Hz.

**I’ve tried a number of different things such as:**

- Ensuring my Ubuntu Nvidia drivers are up to date using the Launchpad
  PPA (I have a Nvidia GTX 670)
- Trying another HDMI cable: The one I’m using now is the one that came
  with my monitor, the other one I tried is the one that came with an Xbox One X. As far as I know they’re both high speed HDMI cables that
  are HDMI 2.0. I also tried both of these cables with Windows and I
  was able to get 2560 x 1440 at 144hz with no issues.
- I did try a DisplayPort cable for my Ubuntu machine and was able to select 120Hz, however this is not ideal because the monitor only has 
  one DisplayPort port which I use for my main Windows PC. So really I 
  need to use my Ubuntu machine with HDMI.
- Downscaling the resolution to 1920 x 1080 on my Ubuntu machine.

None of the above enabled me to select any higher than 60Hz using the Nvidia X Server program.

I would like it so I’m able to use my Ubuntu machine at 2560 x 1440 at 120 / 144Hz via HDMI.

I suspect because the monitor is quite new it might not have much support for Ubuntu yet. Or that there generally isn’t much support for Ubuntu compared to Windows.

I also came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029395/144hz-refresh-rate-ubuntu-18-04-with-nvidia), but that was asked a long time ago, so i'm not sure if it still holds relevance.

If anyone could help me solve this It will be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Nvidia Linux drivers needs more work to have the same features than Windows's nvidia drivers... However, you can edit some file, like this example to force a proper 144hz : https://blog.alexanderkoch.net/2013/144hz-screen-on-linux-nvidia.html